# Python 3.7 - Save and import a file holding Python variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.7

This seems like a pretty obvious/dumb question, but there are a few specifications that make this a bit harder.

Let's say I have a program that takes 3 numbers from a user and does mathematical processes to them to get outputs. Then I `open("file", "r")` to write those variables to a file.

Then, let's say another program then `import`s them and uses them for other processes. I need to be able to import that `file` as Python code. To be clear: **I am not saving text, I am saving python code to a file that is not a .py file.**

Is there any way to save and import Python code to and from a non-`.py` file? And how?

**EDIT:** In the file I'm saving and importing, I'm also saving Python functions. I cannot simply save the variables themselves; I need the variable names, values, and python functions to be saved as normal text in a file, but when I import the file, it should be parsed as Python code.

Comment: Don't save results as python files. Use some file format, that fits best.

Comment: `"I am not saving text, I am saving python code to a file that is not a .py file."` but, why? use pickle, or even plain json. Don't save python code, save data.

Comment: @Daniel That's what I mean, imagine the program outputs `number1=10  number2=20  number3=30`, I want to save that exact python code to a non-python file, but to import it at runtime as if it were normal python code.

Comment: Use some format that is __not__ python, e.g. JSON: `{"number1": 10, "number2": 20}`. This can be easily saved and read with `json.dump` or `json.load`.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I'm not sure I'm being clear. I want to save python code to a non-python file, and import that non-python file as python code. The file is not a `.py` file, but it contains python code that should be parsed in the program as python code when it is imported. EDIT: Just saw your edited comment, I'll check out `json` right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not a good idea to store computation result as code & then import it from elsewhere. You should use a proper data format to store the results - and import it as data. Use JSON or pickle etc.

However, if you do want to shoot yourself in the foot, Python gives you the tools to do that:

Let's say i have some code in a file `temp.txt`

```
number3=30

def f():
    return 'method'
```

Then you can do this:

```
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    code = f.read()
    exec(code)

print(number3)
print(f())
```

Which outputs:

```
30
method
```

Comment: I realise this is a pretty dumb thing to do, but regardless, thank you for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for (even if it's not the smartest way to do things)

Answer (score 0):

If i got this right, this might be done via eval function e.g. you save all code to be executed into a string and then save into a file.

When you need that executed read the file, tke the string and eval it

I must say however that using eval is a bad (very bad) practice and i would advice against it unless there is no other solution that you can find